# gunicorn fails due to an import in __init__.py

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have this line in my appliaction's **init**.py:

```
from .signals import *
```

When I run `gunicorn myproject.wsgi:application`, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/webapps/venv/myproject/myproject/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .signals import *
  File "/webapps/venv/myproject/myproject/signals.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.db.models.query import Q
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.db.models.deletion import Collector
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models import signals, sql
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.subqueries import *
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.query import Query
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 22, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql import aggregates as base_aggregates_module
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/aggregates.py", line 9, in <module>
    ordinal_aggregate_field = IntegerField()
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 495, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 106, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 114, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 62, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 354, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/webapps/venv/myproject/myproject/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .signals import *
  File "/webapps/venv/myproject/myproject/signals.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.db.models.signals import pre_delete
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.db.models.query import Q
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 17, in <module>
    from django.db.models.deletion import Collector
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/deletion.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models import signals, sql
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.subqueries import *
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py", line 12, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql.query import Query
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 22, in <module>
    from django.db.models.sql import aggregates as base_aggregates_module
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/aggregates.py", line 9, in <module>
    ordinal_aggregate_field = IntegerField()
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 116, in __init__
    self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/webapps/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

If I disable the above-mentioned line in the `__init__.py`, gunicorn will start working.
Of course I can move the `import` line to another place and solve the issue, but I wonder why the error happens and if there's another way to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `from .signals import *` it seems you're getting an error due to the execution order.

Based on the error about `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` you need that defined in order to import from a model file.  The issue I think is occurring is that the `__init__.py` file is getting executed when gunicorn goes to load your app, but before Django has actually loaded all of the application settings.

A potential fix may be to define the `__all__` in your `signals.py` file.

Without more context to the issue though, it's tough to know.